# How do I remove the base tag?

Tags: ember-cli

SVGs are broken, and the solution is to remove the base tag and append the urls manually, but I can't find the base tag. Here is the issue in question: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2633

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in config/environment.js in two spots:

```
 var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'projectname',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '/',

  ...

  if (environment === 'test') {
    // Testem prefers this...
    ENV.baseURL = '/';
    ENV.locationType = 'none';
```

Delete those TWO lines and make sure that all of your relative URLs are correct.

Comment: When I delete those lines, I'm unable to reload the app from anything but the root url. Once I'm there all my relative links work fine but I can't load from any other url. Is there a way around this that you know of? In the github issue some mentioned 'hard coding relative paths in the index.html' but I'm not really sure what that means.

Comment: By default Ember is using pushState, right?  I used an nginx rule that would do a silent redirect to index.html for any request under my baseURL (that wasn't a REST call).  Once Ember has reinitialized it figures out the right page to display based on the location.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution is to prepend current pathname to the URL ref.

```
`url(${location.pathname}#${id})`
```

However, this breaks on route transition if the pathname is not bound. You can fix this by binding the `Router`'s url property, but this is getting into the hashish area.

```
var view = this;
var container = view.container;

container.lookup('router:main').get('url'); // Bind this guy
```